# ASP MVC - Pass model data or retrieve from database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller for my Portfolio, and the view model I am using is called DisplayItem. The function of the model is not relevant, but the models represent data about parts of my portfolio.

At the index page for this controller, the top 5 portfolio DisplayItems are built by pulling the required information from a database, and then a collection (List<>) is sent to the view. The view displays previews in a column with buttons to "view the project" for each project displayed. Clicking these buttons will route to the PortfolioController action "Display".

My question is about the efficiency of two methods of sending the appropriate data to the view for the action "Display". I can of course send the ID for the selected DisplayItem, and pull it from the database to rebuild the model and send it to the view. My initial thought was that this is unnecessary work for the database, seeing as I had previously pulled the required information. Though using the ID method would allow me to not pull the rest of the information until necessary.

My alternate idea is to serialize the model (it contains collections that can't be sent with POST), and then post what I need as a string to the action and then serialize into an object.

My experience is by and large not web, it is Game Programming, so I am out of my element to some degree and would love advice on which of the routes to opt for, or if there is some better way to do this.

Comment: Assuming the ID is the PK of your table, getting the object from the database will be blindly fast and is the way you should be doing it. Serializing the model to the view and sending it back again across the wire is the equivalent of trying to mimic `ViewState` in webforms

Comment: Of course, I obviously don't know the details of your application, but there is no reason, in general, why a collection can't be POSTed; it just takes more work. Your fields would have id's like CollectionProperty[0]. That said, you should definitely use the ID and query the database like the others have said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer to query the database again whenever page loads. It allows to

-> check validation of input(id passed)

-> authorization of user for the requested info

-> decrease bandwidth(if data is large).

-> makes routing URL more user friendly(easy to bookmark).

Answer (score 1):

As your application develops over time, your DisplayItem will have increasingly richer information pertaining to it, while your index view will only display summary information.

As the index view and the detail view will eventually require different sets of information, simply pass the ID field over the wire.

As Stepen Muecke says, reading from the database will be fast. Databases are good that way :-)